# Como resgatar o dado que foi salvo no banco durante um processo de criação

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Em alguns ORMs NodeJs tenho esse recurso. Porém, gostaria de saber como fazer para resgatar um entidade que foi persistida no banco?

Por exemplo:
`User` tem um atributo `ID`.
Se eu retornar o item, o `ID` do que foi persistido não vem dentro de `item`.

Eu gostaria de retornar algo do _context do que foi persistido, para que eu venha resgatar o Id.

Segue um modelo genérico que estou usando:

```
    public T Create(T item)
    {
        _dataset.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return item;   
    }
```

Segue classe com métodos básicos:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        protected readonly AimbraDocContext _context;
        private readonly DbSet<T> _dataset;

        public GenericRepository(AimbraDocContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dataset = _context.Set<T>();
        }

        public T Create(T item)
        {
            _dataset.Add(item);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return item;
        }

        public void Delete(long id)
        {
            var result = _dataset.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(id));
            if (result != null)
            {
                _dataset.Remove(result);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public bool Exist(long? id)
        {
            return _dataset.Any(i => i.Id.Equals(id));
        }

        public List<T> FindAll()
        {
            return _dataset.ToList();
        }

        public T FindById(long id)
        {
            var result = _dataset.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(id));
            if (result == null) return null;
            return result;
        }

        public T Update(T t)
        {
            if (!Exist(t.Id)) return null;
            var result = _dataset.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id.Equals(t.Id));
            _context.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(t);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return t;

        }
    }
```

Comment: O ID é auto incremento na sua base?

Comment: Isso... é sim... eu defini ele com o DataAnottation [Key] em na Prop Id.

Comment: Tem que colocar todo o código esse Create tá muito estranho

Comment: Se você esta utilizando `entity framework` e campo auto incremento, o `item.ID` deveria estar preenchido depois do `SaveChanges`. Qual banco de dados você está usando? E poste o código da classe `User`.

Comment: É uma classe genérica. Eu vou atualizar e caso tenha alguma mudança, fique a vontade para fazer com as observações. Estou iniciando agora na linguagem...

Comment: Sua pergunta já foi respondida [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework). Em resumo, o EF6 já implementa o insert com SCOPE_IDENTITY, basta capturar o id do objeto.

Comment: Ah... obrigado! consegui aqui! :)

Comment: Alguém pode responder em Português. Não consigo fechar a questão, porque a plataforma obriga ter resposta em Português.

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é ao invés de usar o Id como int você pode usar o GUID que sempre vai te dar uma sequencia de caracteres.

```
   Id = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Dessa maneira você sempre terá um identificador único e saberá qual ele é antes de registrar no banco.